# Video Element Not Stretching Full Length of Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive design where a video element stretches the full length of its parent div with the class .hero. However, despite my efforts, the video doesn't seem to be expanding to the expected dimensions. Here's the relevant CSS code I'm using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
  <video autoplay muted loop playsinline id="myVideo">
    <source src="/videos/aerial(2).mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
height: 90vh;
width: 100%;
 }

 #myVideo {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: -1; 
   filter: brightness(65%);
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
  }

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
   #myVideo {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #myVideo {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

I've checked for potential issues like z-index conflicts and other conflicting styles, but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem. The video appears to be constrained within the original dimensions and does not fully stretch to match the parent .hero div.

Are there any suggestions or solutions to ensure that the video element properly extends to fill the entire length of the parent div while maintaining responsiveness?

All version of queries work except for regular desktop:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Heres how i would do it**:

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

#myVideo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Center the video */
  z-index: -1;
  filter: brightness(65%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* This makes sure the video covers the entire div */
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #myVideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #myVideo {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <video autoplay muted loop playsinline id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```